# Login after suspend taking an increasingly long time - 18.10

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, 18.10

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (4th gen) that I recently updated to 18.10. Ever since the update, I've had issues with resume after suspend. The biggest is that it takes a long time for the login screen to appear, and the time seems to increase after each suspend-resume cycle.

I took a look at `/var/log/syslog` and I'm seeing a bunch of entries like:

```
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Nov 25 14:38:18 jeremy-thinkpad /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2867]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service --force`, this could fix it.

Comment: The file /usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service doesn't exist (in fact, the whole `system` directory doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `intel_powerclamp` sometimes starts throttling the CPU to the point where it feels below sluggish on my HP Spectre x360. Once I manage to login I run `sudo modprobe -r intel_powerclamp` let things catch up and then add it back with `sudo modprobe intel_powerclamp`. That seems to make things work pretty well. I'm considering removing it on suspend, but haven't pulled the trigger on that.

Check `top` to see if you have a bunch for `kidle_inject` processes. If so, it might be the same issue.