# Login screen takes a long time to open after suspend

Tags: login, suspend, display-manager

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, it takes about a minute for the login screen to appear after closing and reopening my laptop lid or activating suspend directly.

I have tried changing display managers, but the problem persists with both gdm3 and lightdm.

I can switch to tty1 before the login window appears, and it shows a text-based login screen, but this screen is unresponsive (it isn't just that nothing appears when I type the password, pressing enter or any other key does nothing, and I can't even type in a username).

Changing between the proprietary and Noveau graphics drivers does not make a difference.

I have tried both solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098157/login-after-suspend-taking-an-increasingly-long-time-18-10), but it doesn't seem to work. The time it takes for the login screen to appear does not increase over time.

I have a Lenovo Legion Y540 with NVIDIA graphics (TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile]).

**Edit:**

Output of `free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.8Gi       3.7Gi       271Mi       8.0Gi        11Gi
Swap:         7.4Gi          0B       7.4Gi
```

Output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="8b3b6bcf-7b5c-4549-b08b-e33d13f6f8b0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="631c1b82-46a4-42ae-90ca-75f265910d3c"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="81876321-3683-408e-ad1e-48ea9b6e3c07" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b244a4c0-ff1f-4ea0-a0ea-f3c4877e5631"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="4853-74EE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="a684ddb8-dc0e-4259-bf8b-d1b91acfc56c"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="d8d4c311-0089-43bf-85a3-28753acb89c6"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows-SSD" UUID="04E853EAE853D88E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="432f8784-5420-44ef-a3b9-2c33421804ac"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Secondary Drive" UUID="698496af-197c-4bb4-88a4-f1213735f78d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6063bd84-a428-464e-8fcb-e929d0d3e415"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=81876321-3683-408e-ad1e-48ea9b6e3c07 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=4853-74EE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=8b3b6bcf-7b5c-4549-b08b-e33d13f6f8b0 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The directory `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` is empty, the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` does not exist.

**Update**

Some more information:

This behavior happens if I trigger suspend by closing the lid on my laptop and reopening it, or if I run `systemctl suspend`.

If I search `suspend` and run the thing that comes up, something else sometimes happens. My computer instead immediately goes to the login screen. After logging on the screen goes blank and I have to force restart.

As of removing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and running `sudo update-initramfs -c` again (and rebooting), this is what I see when opening the laptop lid:

```
[  61.999380] Freezing of task failed after 20.009 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[  82.151659] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.0007 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[  85.454177] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  85.454812] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  85.455339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
```

Various different iwlwifi messages appear on different tests, and I believe they are unrelated. And right before the system starts, these lines appear:

```
[ 149.082244] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
[ 149.082249] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
[ 188.166140] PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
[ 188.266140] PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

Also a line like this shows up sometimes:

```
[95.820802] wlp0s20f3: failed to remove key (5, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-2)
```

Once while testing this some strange graphics corruption occurred on waking from suspend that seems to affect some images and fonts used by the system (but not any applications). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhdfM.jpg) is a screenshot. This persisted until restarting.

Output of `dpkg -l *nvidia*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                    Architecture Description
+++-================================-==========================-============-=========================================================
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
un  libnvidia-cfg1-any               <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-common                 <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-common-435             435.21-0ubuntu2            all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
un  libnvidia-cfg1-any               <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-common                 <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-common-435             435.21-0ubuntu2            all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-418:amd64      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2 amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-compute-430
rc  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64      430.50-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64      435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:i386       435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
un  libnvidia-decode                 <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
un  libnvidia-encode                 <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
un  libnvidia-fbc1                   <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
un  libnvidia-gl                     <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:amd64           435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:i386            435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
un  libnvidia-ifr1                   <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu2            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
un  libnvidia-ml1                    <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-304                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-340                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-384                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-390                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                    <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-430         430.50-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-435         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-430                  430.50-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-435                  435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
un  nvidia-dkms-kernel               <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-driver-435                435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
un  nvidia-driver-binary             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-common             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-430         430.50-0ubuntu2            amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-435         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
un  nvidia-kernel-source             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-source-430         <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-435         435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-persistenced              <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.13                     all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.1 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
un  nvidia-settings-binary           <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-smi                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-utils                     <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-utils-435                 435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435    435.21-0ubuntu2            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and lastly `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Ok I added that information.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238, which describes my exact problem and has a fix.

I created a new file `suspend-fix.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the contents `blacklist ucsi_ccg`. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` # create this file

With this content...

```
RESUME=UUID=8b3b6bcf-7b5c-4549-b08b-e33d13f6f8b0
```

`sudo update-initramfs -c` # create a fresh initramfs file

`reboot` # reboot the system

Retest suspend/wake.

Comment: I now get an error like `Freezing of tasks failed after 20.002 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0)` on trying to suspend. When it does finally start up a bunch more text appears but the login screen appears before I can read it. If I try to suspend again the old error message shows up in addition to a new one, but the other messages don't.

Comment: @JackStade Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` app, go to the `SMART Data & Tests`. Run the short test first. Then review the data and edit your question with screenshot(s) for me to look at. It may take two screenshots to capture all of the data. To see the text error messages, make a movie of the startup using your smart phone, then you can review/read the movie to read the messages.

Comment: If you have to, you could manually delete the resume file we created, and then re-run the last two commands in my answer.

Comment: @JackStade status please...

Comment: I'm going to be away for a couple days, I will try that on Monday.

Comment: The option for SMART Data & Tests is greyed out for my main drive, presumably because it is NVMe. I found a few potential solutions that I will try hopefully tomorrow. I also added some more information to the original question.

Comment: Lets quickly check two other important things... to get your BIOS version, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and it should be BHCN35WW, released Dec 4th, as per https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds539700. Also, exactly which Nvidia card do you have, and what's the driver version `dpkg -l *nvidia*`.

Comment: The bios version was BHCN28WW, updating it to BHCN35WW didn't change anything. I am using the proprietary nvidia 435 drivers, but I have tried the 430 drivers and nouveau drivers, and there was no change. I added the other information to the original question.

Comment: @JackStade Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry I couldn't help more.